# How to copy multiple files to multiple location based on path?

Tags: bash, macos

On macOS, I have folder structure as below

```
├── src
    └── components
        └── componentA
            └── README.md
        └── componentB
            └── README.md
└── destination
    └── components
        ├── componentA
        └── componentB
```

I am wondering what is the way to copy all `README.md` under `src` to `destination`, mapping based on source, under single command

Comment: Why a single command?

Comment: @Kusalananda: Initially thought it would be nice to have single command to be able to do that as I wanted to register that command as npm scripts

Comment: Do you have any other files there and want to copy only README.md, or can you copy all files from `src/components` to `destination/components`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop in `bash`:

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob dotglob globstar

for srcfile in src/**/README.md; do
    destfile=destination/${srcfile#src/}
    mkdir -p "${destfile%/*}" &&
    cp "$srcfile" "$destfile"
done
```

Here, we use the `**` glob (enabled by setting the `globstar` shell option in `bash`) to loop over all the `README.md` files anywhere below the `src` directory.

For each file, a destination pathname is computed by replacing the initial `src/` string with `destination/`.  The destination directory is then created and the file is copied.

The `nullglob` shell option ensures that the loop won't run at all if the pattern does not match any names, and tho `dotglob` option enables matching of hidden names.

Would you want to copy all `*.md` files, use `*.md` in place of `README.md` in the pattern.

---

You could run the whole thing as a single command from any shell using

```
bash -O globstar -O nullglob -O dotglob -c 'for s in src/**/README.md; do d=destination/${s#src/}; mkdir -p "${d%/*}" && cp "$s" "$d"; done'
```

---

Using `find`, with an additional check to make sure that the `README.md` files found are regular files:

```
find src -type f -name README.md -exec sh -c '
    for srcfile do
        destfile=destination/${srcfile#src/}
        mkdir -p "${destfile%/*}" &&
        cp "$srcfile" "$destfile"
    done' sh {} +
```

It should come as no surprise that the body of the loop in the inline `sh -c` script is *identical* to the loop in the `bash` script at the top.

Answer (score 0):

With `GNU cp`:

```
cd src
cp --parents -t ../destination components/*/README.md
```

Note, that the `cp` version of OSX does not have `--parents` option.

You could use `rsync` then:

```
rsync -av --include '*/' --include='*/README.md' --exclude='*' src/ destination
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy files with [mmv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217683/rename-multiple-files-at-the-same-time/1217686#1217686):

```
$ mmv -n -c 'src/;README.md' 'destination/#1'
```

<sup>Remove `-n` when you feel ready to copy your files.</sup>

Copy files using find and cpio:

```
$ find src/ -type f -name README.md -printf %P\\0 | cpio -p -dm0 -D src/ destination/
```

<sup>cpio will Create leading directories where needed.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Initially thought it would be nice if there is single command that I can register as a npm scripts, but ended up I came up with a solution as below.

```bsh
components=(src/components/*)
for dir in "${components[@]}"; 
do 
  files=($dir/*.md)
  folder_name=${dir##*/}
  for file in "${files[@]}";
  do
    mkdir -p "destination/$folder_name/";
    cp "$file" "destination/$folder_name/";
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

for the given folder structure... just this command line should work

```
cd src; for i in `find . -name README.md`; do cp $i ../destination/$i; done; cd ..
```

Hope it helps